# RavenDB Modeling a Calendar application

Tags: c#, nosql, data-modeling, ravendb, modeling

I am trying out Ravendb for the first time and trying to build up a model for a workout app.
Here is a simple example of the classes that i do not know how to arrange.

```
User{
string:Name
string:Email
//+ 20 or so more properties

}

CalendarEntry{
DateTime:TimeStamp
decimal:Weight
decimal:Waist
List<Meal> Meals
List<WorkoutSession> WorkoutSessions
//+ more properties

}
```

The members will update their training calendar with weight, waist, their daily excersize sessions, food intake with calories and so on. So the list of calendar entries will grow every day.

So the question is, should The user object contain a List of calendar entries or should i be using it as an own Entity Collection with a referring Id to User?

My primary concern is the maximum document size in Ravendb(is there one?) since the List will be growing every day and also the User document might become way too heavy after a year or so if the calendar entries are a nested collection.

Any advice would be appreciated

//Kim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any document size limit in Raven, but your second approach still sounds better... The Calendar entry object looks considerable in size in its own right, so it may end up impairing performance further down the line if a collection of Calendar Entries grows large on each user.

But the question you really need to ask is how will the data be consumed? Are you likely to want to query the database for all Calendar Entries, irrespective of the user? Or in a given time period perhaps? If the answer is yes then you would be better storing the Calendar entries in their own collection, allowing you to optimize indexes for them.

Managing 'foreign keys' between documents is made fairly easy in raven so this should not be too difficult to accomplish. This page details how you handle document relationships: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/handling-document-relationships

Comment: I was thinking about that too, how will i be querying the data. Mostly it is really straight forward. GetAllEntriesByUserId(userI) for example. But there may be somewhere i would want to compare different peoples excersize lenght, excersize type... So i will go for the latter, using calendar entry as its own collection with a UserRefId in each entry. but you see no fundamental modeling error in settings CalendarEntry as its own entity collection?

Comment: Correct, the model described is perfectly acceptable and sustainable.